# Reduction of dimensions in a JPEG image

Tags: jpeg, photo, dimension

I have to reduce the dimensions of a JPG image to exactly 350 * 450 pixels.Please tell how do I do so.My JPG image is of dimensions 392*520 pixels.

### UPDATE:

Ok, thanks for the answers . Checking them now.
Thanks.

Comment: Using a graphics program like The GIMP is probably the easiest. (Load, resize image, save) If you want to keep your content's ratio look for the "Liquid Rescale" plugin (see here http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/) which uses "seam carving" to do the trick for many situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use paint. Go to the resize button (on top of the rotate button) and click the radio box that says pixels. Choose the amount of pixels you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with a linear operation, the ratio of the image will be skewed.
There is nearly 3 % absolute difference, I don't know how much that is to the human perception.

```
350/392 =  0.8929
450/520 =  0.8654
```

I would recommend scaling it to 89% and then cut the rest of the image to get your 350 * 450. This way you would keep the ratios intact.

Comment: How do we do that scaling ?

Comment: With paint like the other answer suggested. But instead of choosing pixels, you choose percentage. So if you want to go from 392 to 350. You have to scale to (350/392) which is about 0.8929 = 89.29%. But you should use the exact values. After that scaling one side has 350 pixels and the other 0.8923 * 520 = 463.996 (~464) pixel. So to get 450 you have to cut 14 pixel from top and/or down.

Answer (score 2):

There are many online resize tools, e.g.: http://www.picresize.com/

Upload your image, enter its new dimensions and download it again.